# Socket Data issue between Android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, sockets, bytebuffer

I'm facing a bit of an issue trying to communicate with 2 devices through a socket (UDP, but not the issue here...)
One device is Android, the other is iOS.

Here's the Android code to create the Data I'm sending :

```
int part = 1;
int num = -1;

ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(20);
bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
bb.putChar('R');
bb.putInt(part);
bb.putInt(num);
bb.flip();

byte[] toSend = new byte[bb.remaining()]; // bb.remaining() = 10
bb.get(toSend);

send(toSend);
```

On iOS, here's the code I use to parse the data I get from the socket

```
char *sData = (char*)[data bytes];
if (sData[0] == 'R') {
        sData += sizeof(char);
        int part = 0;
        memcpy(&part, sData, sizeof(int));
        sData += sizeof(int);
        int num = 0;
        memcpy(&num, sData, sizeof(int));
}
```

The data I get is :

```
part = 256
num = -256
```

The weird thing is if I change value from the Android device I get :

```
part = 0 & num = -1 ---> part = 0 & num = -256
part = 1 & num = -1 ---> part = 256 & num = -256
part = 2 & num = -1 ---> part = 512 & num = -256
part = 3 & num = -1 ---> part = 768 & num = -256
```

As you can see, the value are correct, they are just multiplied by 256, and I can't understand why...

To avoid compatibility issue between Android and iOS (32/64) I avoided the long type, because on

```
Android long = 8
iOS 32b long = 4
iOS 64b long = 8
```

Does anybody can see why it is multiplying my value by 256 ?

**EDIT 1 :**

From iOS to iOS data transfer, it is working fine, so my guess is that the bug is coming from Android.

Comment: Are you sure that NativeOrder is correct?  Have you tried using LittleEndian? -256 is what I'd expect to see if the byte order were reversed.

Comment: @Simon yeah, nativeOrder and LittleEndian gave me the same result. Of course BigEndian give me a mess ;-)

Comment: OK, well you could eliminate the possibility of a Java bug by examining the byte array in the debugger.  I don't see how it could be a bug in such basic operations.  The other observation is that shifting an int value by 8 bits to the left multiples by 256.  Are you indexing the buffer in iOS correctly?  I don't know ObjectiveC but does memcpy advance the buffer pointer?

Comment: That's what I don't get either, but when I retrieve data from the buffer, it does give me correct value... However the weird thing is also that the ByteBuffer, should be a size of 9 not 10... if we do the count: char + int + int = 1 + 4 + 4 = 9 ≠ 10

Comment: Hmm, a Java char is 2 bytes.  2+4+4=10?

Comment: @Simon : as far as I know memcpy does not move the buffer pointer

Comment: Hmmm... that should be then the issue here... on C language, char size is only one...

Comment: Looks to me that you are reading the first int starting at the second byte but it actually starts at the 3rd byte.

Comment: Yeah unfortunately, I can't change the iOS version to read 2 bits from the socket (version is already out), how can I add the character R to be only 1bit on the bytebuffer ?

Comment: Well, the bug is on the iOS side so you might want to consider a fix since it it not platform independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, your buffer contains this:

```
char 2 bytes | int 4 bytes | int 4 bytes
```

Since iOS stores char in one byte, you are reading it as if it were:

```
char 1 byte | int 4 bytes | int 4 bytes
```

This also explains why iOS -> iOS works.

[Edit]

To fix, you could use `byte` in Java.

```
byte b = (byte) 'R';
```

Like this:

```
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(20);
bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
bb.putByte((byte)'R');
bb.putInt(part);
bb.putInt(num);
bb.flip();
```

Note though that casting char to byte "loses" the high 8 bits so this will only work for ASCII chars.

Comment: That is a correct answer ! how can I add to the ByteBuffer the char 'R' to take only 1 bit ?

Comment: that's not a big problem to get ASCII, since I'll only use from A to Z value ;-), thank you again